# Checking users within spasfic group in weblogic server for web service application

Tags: java, oracle, web-services, soap, weblogic

I built simple web service application with policy(`Wssp1.2-2007-Https-UsernameToken-Plain.xml`) in **jdeveloper 11.1.1.7** and deploy it **weblogic 10.3**. Everything works fine both in the client and server side.

The client side can not invoke any method without specifying username/password properties. The server automatically checks the user values in users define within weblogic server in the following path (**Summary of Security Realms>myrealm>Users and Groups**).

By this the client can access the system if he enters any of the users in this group even with the default user weblogic/weblogic.

**Question: How to restrict the username/password checking with in specific group of users?**. i.e if the client mention username/password outside the group(even if the values are correct) the server will reject the request

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using the weblogic "default" authentication method for users, you can do the following to set up a policy for group access:

- Login to the weblogic admin console
- Click the deployments links
- Select your webservice
- Click the Security tab
- Click the Policies sub-tab
- Choose your authorization provider from the drop down (sounds like the default)
- Choose Add Conditions -> Group -> Type in the group name
- Finish

Now only the group you have added should be able to invoke the web service. All other users should see something like:

`javax.xml.ws.soap.SOAPFaultException: Access denied to operation myWebService`

Comment: Please refer to the following question, you may have answer: [How to restrict access to web-service application deployed in weblogic for group of user only](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24675542/how-to-restrict-access-to-web-service-application-deployed-in-weblogic-for-group)